# How to override the system locale on a single command?

Tags: command-line, locale

When helping someone we often ask them to show the output of a command eg:

```
sudo fdisk -l | pastebinit
```

If the user is not using an English locale, the output may be in a foreign language:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 huvuden, 63 sektorer/spår, 91201 cylindrar, totalt 1465149168 sektor
```

This complicates support. How can one run a command with an override on the system locale to get English output?

Comment: The answer is something like "LANG=C sudo fdisk -l | pastebinit" but I can't remember the exact, and google is failing me, plus I can't test because I use English...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The environment variables to override with the locale you wish to use are `LANG`, `LC_ALL`, and `LANGUAGE`. Some apps will handle some of these differently, but generally just setting `LANG` should work. You can run a command in the terminal with it, like `LANG=es_ES locale`. The `locale` command will show the current environment variable settings for your locale.

Comment: LANG=es_ES <command> doesn't actually work if you don't have that locale installed, but this is the confirmation I was looking for. LANG=C <command> gives the built-in strings always.