# Why does the bluetooth indicator not show?

Tags: 12.10, indicator, bluetooth, headset

Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit

```
$ psg blue
simon     2852  2713  0 15:15 ?        00:00:00 bluetooth-applet
root      4143     1  0 15:17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd

$ gsettings get com.canonical.indicator.bluetooth visible
true

$ rfkill unblock bluetooth
Can't open RFKILL control device: No such file or directory

$ rfkill list all
Can't open RFKILL control device: No such file or directory

$ dmesg | grep blue
<nothing>
```

[image: Bluetooth configuration]

I use a USB Bluetooth dongle. My PC haven't bluetooth integrated.
I can enable bluetooth and pair one headset (*like it shows the screenshot*).
But the bluetooth indicator isn't showed.
What's the problem?

Comment: I think that [this post](http://askubuntu.com/q/246547/62483) could be useful for you :)

Comment: I haven't any problem with language.

Comment: No, no. I didn't mean that. I was referring to the screenshoot. Is just a help, it won't solve your problem.