# Is it possible to launch an application in a language other than the system language?

Tags: 12.04, geany

I want to launch Geany in a language other than the system default English. How can I do that ?

Comment: Please note that in spite of its title, [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/246547/is-it-possible-to-change-language-for-user-interface-temporarily) *does* actually tell you how to launch a single application with a different language than the rest of the *concurrently* running system (including other applications).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the language before starting Geany with ...

```
LANG_ALL={language} geany
```

and it will show Geany in Dutch.

Here is a [list of possible languages](http://i18n.geany.org/) with the translation files (in case you do not have that yet) and translation progress.

By the way: this will work with more programs. Not just Geany.

Comment: I had tried that. I get an error message saying 'Locale is not supported by C library. Using the fallback locale`.

Comment: So use one that is supported ;) Btw: see the dupe since it explains it better.

Comment: Do I need the language packages/support installed for the OS as well ? Because the language I want to use is listed there for Geany.