# Why is overriding the LANG environment variable not changing the language for me?

Tags: environment-variables, language-support, translation

I'm trying to run an application in another language as my current environment. To start out simple, I wanted to change the language of `ls`.

Here's what I read all over the place (see below for related questions): set `LANG` to one of the supported locales, e.g.:

```
LANG=nl_NL.UTF-8 ls /nonexistent
```

to have it show Dutch (NL) output.

However, I still get English output:

```
$ LANG=nl_NL.UTF-8 ls -al /nonexistent
ls: cannot access /nonexistent: No such file or directory
```

My current environment:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

To be sure, I've checked:

- The locale is supported:

  ```
  $ grep nl_NL /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED 
  nl_NL.UTF-8 UTF-8
  nl_NL ISO-8859-1
  nl_NL@euro ISO-8859-15
  ```
- The locale is generated:

  ```
  sudo locale-gen nl_NL.UTF-8
  ```

  and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` also shows it's generated.
- Installed the Dutch language pack (already installed):

  ```
  sudo apt-get install language-pack-nl
  ```

What else have I tried?

- Using `export` to set both `LANG` and `LANGUAGE` instead of prepending the command.
- Setting also `LC_ALL`.

Ironically, some (only some!) GUI applications are actually in Dutch, but I haven't configured that at all!

[image]

I'm on Kubuntu 12.04(.2), as far as that matters.

Similar questions (to no avail):

- [Is it possible to change language for user interface temporarily?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246547/is-it-possible-to-change-language-for-user-interface-temporarily)
- [How to override the system locale on a single command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220774/how-to-override-the-system-locale-on-a-single-command)
- [Temporarily change language for terminal messages/warnings/errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142812/temporarily-change-language-for-terminal-messages-warnings-errors) (demonstrated to be working, but not working for me)
- [How do I add locale to ubuntu server?](https://askubuntu.com/q/76013/88802)

**What's wrong on my system? Where to debug this further?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because LANGUAGE, which takes precedence over LANG, is set and unchanged.

```
$ LANGUAGE=nl ls /nonexistent
ls: kan geen toegang krijgen tot /nonexistent: Bestand of map bestaat niet
```

More info is in the [GNU gettext documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#The-LANGUAGE-variable):

> GNU gettext gives preference to LANGUAGE over LC_ALL and LANG for the purpose of message handling, but you still need to have LANG (or LC_ALL) set to the primary language; this is required by other parts of the system libraries.

Comment: I'd swear I had tried this already. Yet, looking at my shell history, I think this is because I only tried this *before* generating the locale. Could you include a source for why "LANGUAGE takes precedence over LANG"? Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Locale-Environment-Variables