# Change git's language to English without changing the locale

Tags: language-support, git

My locale is German. `LANG=de_DE.UTF-8`. I would like to keep it.

Is it possible to change **git**'s language to English without changing the locale?

Comment: Why dosn't the line `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` work for you?

Comment: This is also discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633564/how-does-one-change-the-language-of-the-command-line-interface-of-git

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can add alias to you .bashrc or .bash_profile

```
alias git='LANG=en_US.UTF-8 git'
```

If `LANG` doesn't work, try `LC_ALL` or `LANGUAGE`

Comment: run source .bashrc in command line

Comment: @sergej Does the `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 git` command work for you?

Comment: So it doesn't work. Before create an alias, you need to make this command work. Do you have the English language installed?

Comment: try LC_ALL instead LANG

Comment: For the discussion on `LANG` vs `LANGUAGE` vs `LC_ALL`: [Why is overriding the LANG environment variable not changing the language for me?](http://askubuntu.com/q/311767/88802)

Comment: But this method will change the language not only for git, but for the whole terminal session, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
echo "export LANGUAGE='en_US.UTF-8 git'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, git version 1.9.1

Comment: This solution is wrong. First of all: The value for LANGUAGE is invalid. `git` is not allowed there. Second: You are setting the language for your whole bash session. It will affect other programs as well.

Comment: This answer is confused about what `LANGUAGE` does.