# How can I change the shell to english? (I especially need this for git.)

Tags: command-line, 15.04

I'd like to know how I can change my shell language (not the OS) to english. The language I have in my OS windows is German (Switzerland).

Answer: I've put `export LC_ALL=C` into the hidden `~/.bashrc` file as some suggested. This solved my problem.

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm: Afaik I don't have two languages. The menus and everything are German.

Comment: you can make the settings permanent by putting `export LC_ALL=C` at the bottom of `.bashrc` file

Comment: @kos Pity! It wasn't an answer. If it was, you'd get another upvotes ;)

Comment: edward torvalds: What is a .bashrc file? Please provide a full answer. Thanks.

Comment: @empedokles: put `export LC_ALL=C` at the end of `~/.bashrc`, which is a hidden text file named `.bashrc` in your home directory.  To see it, open your home directory in Files and hit CTRL+H. Save, exit and then fire up a terminal. Everything should be in English. After that, if that solved your problem, please agree with the closure of the question by clicking the button "Yes, that solved my problem!".

Comment: kos: That didn't help, it may consider other parts of the shell, but "git" is still in German, if I use "git push .... etc (the provided link doesn't contain the helpful information about the .bashrc btw.).

Comment: Ok, please edit you question and explain that you tried this and that it didn't work for `git`. Maybe also change the title to explain that the problem is mostly related to `git` since `export LC_ALL=C` at least partially solved the problem.

Comment: I found this: http://askubuntu.com/q/320661/380067. The first answer applies only to `git`, the second one applies to all executables relying on `LANG` (hence also e.g. to `date`).

Comment: I think even the first answer solved it, but it didn't until I restarted the shell. ;-)

Comment: Can you figure out which one of the two solved it? E.g. remove the line from the second question and restart the shell, so that I know what to vote for. :) Or flag your question yourself, it's the same.

Comment: @kos: The one writen in my question above.