# How to have GUI in Dutch and terminal output in English?

Tags: command-line, language-support, locale

I've got Ubuntu installed with Dutch as my language. I often work in the terminal and many of the outputs are in Dutch as well. This is very inconvenient though, because I often need to search for error messages I get, and on the interwebs error messages are unfortunately easier found in English than in Dutch.

Is there a way to have all terminal output in English, while all GUI's are in Dutch?

All tips are welcome!

Comment: You can get English command output by simply prefixing the command with `LANG=C`, e.g. `LANG=C sudo apt update`. You can also type `LANG=C` on its own and it will last until you close that terminal window.

Comment: To set `LANG=C` automatically for every new terminal session just add the command to your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @ByteCommander: The duplicate question focuses on changing it temporarily, while my interpretation of the OP's desire is a permanent change. If there is no more suitable duplicate question, I think this one shouldn't be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change it persistently, so you always have English when opening a terminal window, open the `~/.bashrc` file for editing and add these lines:

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Why `en_US` and not `C` as suggested by commenters?

Comment: @Melebius: Setting `LANG=C` disables UTF-8 encoding, and I'm not sure that's generally a good idea. Besides, this approach applies also if you want to enable some other language but English for the terminal.

Comment: What is the difference between `LANG` and `LANGUAGE`? Why does one need or want to set both?

Comment: @dessert: https://askubuntu.com/questions/311767/why-is-overriding-the-lang-environment-variable-not-changing-the-language-for-me `LANGUAGE` is set more often than not in Ubuntu. `LANG=C` is special; if you do that, you automatically disable `LANGUAGE`.